# What is the correct way to attribute FreeForm submissions to users?

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

I'm using FreeForm and need to create a relationship between form submissions and the user that submitted them.

To accomplish this I created a hidden variable on my form called userId.  I use overridesValues to set the userId to the current user before I render the form.  This "feels" wrong to me .. is there a better way to do this?   Is this userId already stored in the freemform data model (making what I'm doing uncessesary)?

```
{% requireLogin %} {#check user is logged in #}
{{ craft.freeform.form("employeeForm", {
  overrideValues: {
    userId: currentUser.id,
  }
}).render() }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually saw that earlier in the documents: https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/overview/relations.html#overview

Comment: reading now but this looks really promising ... amazing how i can miss stuff like that even after reading docs/google/etc ... thanks!